# Find solution of signle element $y_i$ in vector $y$ subject to $Ay=c$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have a interesting question about linear algebra problem. Assume that I have a matrix $A^{m \times n}$ and vector $c^{n \times 1}$ are known and I want to find the solution of vector y subject to $$Ay=c$$

The common method is Gaussian elimination. However, this method will find all element solution of vector y and take long time. My goal is that I find only single element $y_i$ of vector $y$, instead of find all element solution of $y=${$y_1,y_2....y_i..y_m$}. Could you suggest to me any way or method with low complexity to resolve my problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would suggest using the substitution method of solving systems of linear equation (the one that is taught in high school). That method gets you "one value at a time" and you can just work it out so that the value of the single $y_i$ that you need (if there is a specific one you want) is the one that pops out first.

Comment: @mapierce271: It is not good solution. Many possible method can do it, let read the section B in this paper. https://www.dropbox.com/s/aqi6bro82762a83/2013_T-W%20Improving%20LT%20Decoding_With%20Wiedemann%20Solve.pdf?dl=0 . However, this paper is very complex and I would like to find the other method. Thank